# How to remove alphanumeric character in brackets & all its increasing values

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I need to erase from a MS Word 2010 paragraphs all characters that contain [P1]...[PXXXXX] mean all P1 (+n) increasing values eg. I would like to delete all words (including the [ and ])

[P1], [P2],[P3], [P4]....,[P250]

Is there a VBA or something to use to quickly delete all these?

Comment: Use find and replace with wildcards and replace the found strings with nothing.

Comment: Thanks but then I have to do than 250 times... :( I need a solution that I that erases all [PXXX] values at once...

Comment: No you don't. Use a wildcard match, something like `[9999]`. You should only need to do it once.

Comment: nope... I need to erase [P100] [P158] etc

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-and-other-data-in-a-Word-document-c6728c16-469e-43cd-afe4-7708c6c779b7

Comment: could you be more specific? i'm not familiar with extensive Search and replace...

Comment: Sorry, I'm on mobile and can't access a PC right now. You don't need VBA to do this (unless you want a lot of extra work). You need to use a wildcard search to tell Word to "find all occurrences of `[` followed by 1 to 5 (or however many the maximum # of numbers are in your unwanted text) numbers that are `0` through `9` followed by `]`" and replace each occurrence with nothing (i.e. leave the *Replace with* box empty). Wildcards do this. See [this page](http://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm) and IGNORE the mention of VBA.

Comment: THANK YOU for your advises.There were the best!! As it appears the appropriate wildcard was  (\[)P[0-9]*(\])

Answer (score -1):

As suggested by @Twisty, it appears the appropriate wildcard was `(\[)P[0-9]*(\])`